# Perl grep exact value in array

Tags: perl

I have the following values in an array:

```
test1|value1
test2|value2
test3|value3
```

Code:

```
if (grep(/test1|value1/, @array)) {
    print "Found";
}
```

I want the above code to only find exact match of "test1|value1" but it is returning found even if I run:

```
if (grep(/test3|value4/, @array)) {
    print "Found";
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to scape the column (`|`) to match the column character. Otherwise is interpreted as an _or_. Try with `/test1\|value1/`

Comment: Ah great spot, thank you - Please add this as an answer.

Comment: If you want just find (any)one matched value, you don't need `grep` the whole array. Especially on the large arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe `|` inside a regex is interpreted as `or`. It is documented in [`perlreref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#SYNTAX).

> `|       Matches either the subexpression preceding or following it`

So, If you want to match the words containing `|` you need to escape it inside regex. Now It is `OK`, but there is one problem it will also match `test1|value1someothervalue` or `someothervaluetest1|value1` or `someothervaluetest1|value1someothervalue` etc.

But, you told you need exact match `test1|value1`. So, again from [`perlreref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#SYNTAX) you need anchor `^` and dollar `$` before and after your regex.

> ```
>  ^       Matches at the beginning of the string (or line, if /m is used)
>  $       Matches at the end of the string (or line, if /m is used)
> ```

So, It will become:

```
if (grep(/^test1\|value1$/, @array)) {
    print "Found\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `grep`

```
use feature qw(say);

my @array = qw(test1|value1
               test2|value2
               test3|value3);

foreach(@array){
       say "Found" if /test1\|value1/;
}
```